# How to call a stored procedure using table values when scalar is expected

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

So I'm not an SSRS guru, but I've inherited this SSRS report from someone who is better with SQL. Basically, in SSRS there are parameters at the top of the report, and you can select one, several, or all options in this table of string values.

I'm trying to manually execute the SP, but it's expecting scalar values for something that is not scalar in the SSRS front end. There has to be some way to wrap this up other than one-by-one every possible combination of single selections.

I'll post some code if needed, but I thought this was very straight forward.

• SSRS front end has parameter options for the report

• SP for this report is expecting only one value at a time

EDIT:
This is how the SP is doing it for one of the variables:

```
DECLARE @IBA_list TABLE (IBA VARCHAR(20))
INSERT @IBA_list (IBA) SELECT DISTINCT * from  dbo.splitstring(@IBA)
```

But the problem is that I have to SELECT * FROM IBA_table to get these values, and in this way, I cannot use the splitstring function.

I've tried just passing the values, and I just get a scalar exepected issue, which makes total sense.

Comment: I'm going to use something that will take a column of table values and concatenate them into a uniform string. I'll leave this open if anyone has any other suggestions. I will post my solution when it's built.

https://www.sqlmatters.com/Articles/Converting%20row%20values%20in%20a%20table%20to%20a%20single%20concatenated%20string.aspx

Comment: The results are expected by the SP as 'text1, text2, text3, text4', which then uses the dbo.splitstring function to parse out the values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically, if you have a multi-valued parameter then the SQL statement in the dataset query might contain a where clause that uses `IN`. e.g.

```
SELECT * FROM Employees WHERE Department IN (@dept)
```

If the users chooses, say "accounts" and "sales" then SSRS injects this into the statement, you can see this if you run a trace on the server. So what will actually get executed on the server will be

```
SELECT * FROM Employees WHERE Department IN ('accounts', 'sales')
```

If you run the trace you'll see the query that actually gets used and how the parameters are passed, but the simplest approximation would be something like

```
declare @paramValues varchar(100) = '''sales'',''accounts'''
declare @sql varchar(max)
set @sql = replace('SELECT * FROM Employees WHERE Department IN (@dept)', '@dept', @paramValues)
exec (@sql)
```

Comment: A very nice explanation, but the issue is that it's hard coded. For the sake of your example, "Departments" is a moving target as departments come and go. The SP is expecting a string value like 'dept1, dept2, dept3, etc', which it then splits via function.

Are you suggesting to modify the SP so that it can expect a table instead of the string value and use the IN logic to filter? If I had to explore all roads, this would technically be a solution. I was going to avoid modifying the SP (since SSRS depends on it), but I could duplicate and modify it to meet your solution.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood, I thought you were trying to replicate a dataset query for testing. It's a different process with an SP. If you simply want to pass a comma separated list to your SP, you can pass an expression such as `=JOIN(Parameters!@dept.Value, “,”)` where `@dept` is the name of your SSRS parameter.

Comment: I figured it out. Basically the SP is expecting a list of values, like 'value1, value2, value3', and passing those values worked.